# How can I undo a TextBox's text changes caused by a binding?

Tags: wpf, textbox, wpf-controls, binding

I have a `TextBox` to which i bound a string, if i now edit the text manually i will be able to undo those changes via `TextBox.Undo()`, if however i change the string and the TextBox's text is updated, i cannot undo those changes and the `TextBox.CanUndo` property will always be `false`.
I suppose this might have to do with the complete replacement of the text rather than a modification of it.

Any ideas on how i can get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried Mode=TwoWay in your binding string?

Comment: Never mind, TwoWay binding didn't work...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, started to leave a comment and realized it was an answer :)

TextBox.Undo() is intended to undo a user's interaction with the text box not a value change in the property it's bound to.  A change in the property the text box is bound to will just update the value of the TextBox, this is a different change than a user edit via focus/keyboard.  If you need to Undo changes to your bound properties you probably need to investigate adding an Undo/Redo stack to your application.

Comment: I suspected that there would not be a simple solution, then again, it was not really a good idea to try and handle undoing by reverting a change that occurred in a control, rather than the model. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I was facing the same issue (needed to accept input upon <kbd>Enter</kbd> and revert to original value upon <kbd>Escape</kbd>) and was able to handle it this way:

1. Set `UpdateSourceTrigger` of your `TextBox.Text` binding to `Explicit`.
2. Handle `KeyDown` event of your TextBox and put the following code in there:

   ```
   if (e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Escape)
   {
     BindingExpression be = ((TextBox)sender).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);

     if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
     {
       if (be != null) be.UpdateSource();
     }
     else if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
     {
       if (be != null) be.UpdateTarget(); //cancels newly supplied value and reverts to the original value
     }
   }
   ```

I found this solution to be very elegant because it can be used in DataTemplates too. For example in my case I used it to allow in-place editing of ListBox items.

Comment: This does not cover the case where immediate value propagation is desired. You probably would want to save on lost focus as well. Still, it might be a decent work around in some cases.

Answer (score 5):

Assign directly to the TextBox:

```
textBox.SelectAll();
textBox.SelectedText = newText;
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, this is about the undo functionality, i know how to overwrite existing text. There is no `newText`, i was trying to restore an old value that should have been stored in the TextBox's history.

Comment: @H.B. This works great! Doesn't overwrite the clipboard, and allows you to undo text assignments that weren't made by the user! Thanks Pixar! H.B. I would consider rewarding Pixar with the answer, since this does exactly what you asked for in the question.

Comment: @Darkhydro: No, unfortunately the question is about text changes caused by bindings, i.e. the property that the `TextBox.Text` is bound to is changed, no interaction with the `TextBox` itself.

Comment: This can be easily expanded to do what you want with an attached property, so you can do something like `UserText.Value="{Binding Xyz}"` which updates the text using the method in this answer when it changes instead of using the Text property directly. I know this answer is old, but might be of interest to someone coming by it now.

Answer (score 1):

The TextBox will apply the changes to the internal undo stack if they are applied in such a way that they appear to have come from the user, like so:

```
        Clipboard.SetText("NewTextHere");
        TextBox.Paste();
```

It's a terrible workaround, as it kills whatever the user has on the clipboard (the restoring of which is pessimistically discussed here: [How do I backup and restore the system clipboard in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578900/how-do-i-backup-and-restore-the-system-clipboard-in-c)) but I thought it might be worth having posted nonetheless.

Comment: An interesting idea at the very least. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think the ViewModel Undo/Redo article is a good one, but it's as much as about the ViewModel pattern as it is about how to write custom Undo/Redo functionality. Also, in response to confusedGeek, I think there could be examples where undoing changes in your model, not just in your individual controls is appropriate (say you had a textbox and a slider both bound to the sample property, you want to undo a change regardless of which control made it, so we're talking about app level undo instead of control level).

So given that, here is a simple, if not somewhat kludgey example of doing precisely what you ask using a CommandBinding and a simplistic undo stack:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyString", typeof(String), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

    // The undo stack
    Stack<String> previousStrings = new Stack<String>();
    String cur = ""; // The current textbox value
    Boolean ignore = false; // flag to ignore our own "undo" changes

    public String MyString
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(MyStringProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyStringProperty, value); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;

        // Using the TextChanged event to add things to our undo stack
        // This is a kludge, we should probably observe changes to the model, not the UI
        this.Txt.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(Txt_TextChanged);

        // Magic for listening to Ctrl+Z
        CommandBinding cb = new CommandBinding();
        cb.Command = ApplicationCommands.Undo;
        cb.CanExecute += delegate(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        };

        cb.Executed += delegate(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (previousStrings.Count > 0)
            {
                ignore = true;
                this.Txt.Text = previousStrings.Pop();
                ignore = false;
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        };

        this.CommandBindings.Add(cb);
    }

    void Txt_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ignore)
        {
            previousStrings.Push(cur);
        }

        cur = this.Txt.Text;
    }

    private void SetStr_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyString = "A Value";
    }
}
```

And here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestUndoBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel  Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBox Name="Txt" Text="{Binding Path=MyString, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Button Name="SetStr" Click="SetStr_Click">Set to "A Value"</Button>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

In this example the behavior is slightly different than typical TextBox undo behavior because 1) I'm ignoring selection, and 2) I'm not grouping multiple keystrokes into a single undo step, both of which are things you would want to consider in a real app, but should be relatively straightforward to implement yourself.