# Clipboard fail to restore data with setdataobject

Tags: c#, wpf, clipboard

I got a problem with restoring the data here is the code if you read the comments then I ll think you ll understand the problem, and hopefuly know how to fix this.

```
var oldclip = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetDataObject(); //Here we save the clipboard
var oldpoint = CursorPosition;
CursorPosition = new System.Drawing.Point((Convert.ToInt32((rect.Width - rect.X) * 0.45) + rect.X), Convert.ToInt32((rect.Height - rect.Y) * 0.75) + rect.Y);
DoLeftMouseClick();
SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^a^c{ESCAPE}"); // here we go select all text and then copy it to the clipboard
if (System.Windows.Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)) //if the clipboard has text then we do something with it to get that info in the blabla here
{
    //...blabla //
}
System.Windows.Clipboard.SetDataObject(oldclip); // HERE I want to restore the clipboard but that fails! After this when I CTRL+P(paste) then it returns nothing,(while it should still have the same "oldclip" data no??
```

EDIT: I got a better idea how to explain my problem. Lets say I got 2 buttons, button save & button restore.
We got a variable:

```
 IDataObject oldclip;
```

Button save code is:

```
oldclip = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetDataObject();
```

The we got the restore button code

```
System.Windows.Clipboard.SetDataObject(oldclip);
```

Now I copy some text "randomtext123". I press the save button. Then I go and copy some other text "otherrandomtext".
Now if I press the restore button, I want the clipboard data to be "randomtext123" again but this doesn t happen.(Because if I paste after the resto button it doesn t do anything, like there is nothing on the clipboard). Hope you understand the problem better now :)

Answer (score 3):

This should produce the desired result:

```
public class ClipboardBackup
{
    Dictionary<string, object> contents = new Dictionary<string,object>();

    public void Backup()
    {
        contents.Clear();
        IDataObject o = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        foreach (string format in o.GetFormats())
            contents.Add(format, o.GetData(format));
    }

    public void Restore()
    {
        DataObject o = new DataObject();

        foreach (string format in contents.Keys)
        {
            o.SetData(format, contents[format]);
        }

        Clipboard.SetDataObject(o);
    }
}
```

P.S. you might not want to do this. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2579846/305865

Answer (score 0):

Per the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597039.aspx), if you want to use the system clipboard, you must set the permission to AllClipboard:

> for permission to access data on the system Clipboard. Associated
>   enumeration: AllClipboard

I just tested, and running this code in your codebase will fix the problem:

```
    UIPermission clipBoard = new UIPermission(PermissionState.None);
    clipBoard.Clipboard = UIPermissionClipboard.AllClipboard;
```

Comment: When I do this, then I am able to paste but only in the form(in a textbox) not outside it ^^? (So if I go to the textbox and paste it works, if I go to chrom and paste, it doesn t work)

Comment: @Maximc Can you update the code in your question with what you are trying? As I stated, I tested this and it worked for me